# How to get dropdown option label from POST request?

Tags: php

I have this array that populates a dropdown menu. The key is my database key and the value is the corresponding database value. The issue I am having is that when I POST the form, I am getting the POSTed numerical value instead of the string value in the dropdown list. I could query the database to get the string but there has to be a better way of doing this as I already have both values in an array. I can't use array_search because the the array is multidimensional. Can someone please offer a hand?

Thanks

```
foreach($dd as $k=>$v)
{
    echo'<option value="'.$v['ace_id'].'">'.$v['arua'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: You realize that the browser will post whatever is in the value= attribute of the selected <option>? Can you clarify what you're putting there versus what you're getting back?

Comment: Hey Dark. Yes, I know.. I am using the key for the html value that is posted. I need it for the database however, when the user posts and the validation fails, I need to show the user the string, not the db key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `input` fields (this also includes `select`, `textarea` and `button`) only sends the *name-value* pairs to the server side (as been specified in the `name` and `value` attribues). They does **not** send any textual representation along it.

You already know the text and the labels in the server side beforehand (how else would you have printed them?), there's absolutely no point of having them in the request parameters.

You can solve this "problem" in several ways:

1. Just specify the desired value in the option `value` attribute, not as option label.
2. Add hidden input field(s) which passes the option label back.
3. Maintain a global array in the server side memory with those key-value pairs.
4. Go get the value from the DB.
5. Do nothing. In most cases you actually don't need them, just write smart code.

**Update**: here's a basic example (without sanitity checks like `isset` and `htmlspecialchars`, but that's up to you):

```
$selected = $_POST['dropdownname'];

foreach ($options as $value => $label) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '"' . ($value == $selected ? ' selected' : '') .  '>' . $label . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'd opt for #5 and that's what I've been trying to do. Drop downs have always been a bit of a challenge to get just right with a minimal amount of code when using the same form for inserts, updates and deletes. How would you go about doing this if it were you?

Comment: Set the option to selected if the array key matches the request parameter value.

Comment: Ok, that sounds super easy... Almost too easy. If you look at my array, the way it's structured, how would I test the array key? array_search wouldn't work with this type of array. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text name in the dropdown instead of the key, then put that in the value="" part.  If you want both, then put both in there and seperate them with a comma and run split() on it.

Comment: This was what I had thought of originally doing and then using explode.. or split. Yes, this would work too. I figured that maybe there was a best practice for these dropdowns. I have always struggled with getting them just right and thought that I'd ask over here.