# How to get tag text using flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am creating a flask form where i have dropdown list with values, i want to get the text of the drop down list.

for examples:
this is my dropdown list

```html
<select name="city" id="cty" nameinerr="City" required="true">
      
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
  <optgroup label="Delhi / NCR (All)"><option value="6" class="">Delhi Central</option><option value="220" class="">Delhi Dwarka</option><option value="4" class="">Delhi East</option><option value="2" class="">Delhi North</option>
```

If i select delhi east, i want to get the name which is delhi east and also the value, my code is able to get the value but not the text.

Please help

Below is my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,make_response, request
import os
from flask import redirect, url_for, request, send_file
import sys
import sqlite3
import datetime
from datetime import date
import csv
import io
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import functools
import time
#from Frontend import main

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def main():
    if request.method=="POST":
        data = request.form.get("city")
        datas = request.name["city"]# dont know what do here..
        print(data, ">>>", datas)
##        r = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000").text
##        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
##        data = soup.find_all("option")
##        for i in data:
##            new = request.form.get("city").text
##            print(new)

    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe HTML is designed to pass on only the name-value in the request parameters when you post. It does not pass anything else.

If you have the control over the HTML, you could  include the text in the value, in your case for example 
value=4-Delhi East

And then parse it in your code. 
Alternatively if you dont have access to the HTML, you can fetch the form via requests, you could then parse it with beautiful soup and create a dictionary of value and options text.

hope this helps. 
Also look at this answer which has more options, 
[How to get dropdown option label from POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961253/how-to-get-dropdown-option-label-from-post-request)